# regex multi line match after string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to extract the `PROCEDURE` section out of `CLAIM`, `EOB` & `COB` from a text file.

and create an object like so

```
claim : [{PROCEDURE1}, {PROCEDURE2}, {PROCEDURE3}],
eob : [{PROCEDURE1}, {PROCEDURE2}, {PROCEDURE3}],
cob: [{PROCEDURE1}, {PROCEDURE2}, {PROCEDURE3}]
```

```js
let data = `    SEND CLAIM {
       PREFIX="9403        "
       PROCEDURE { /* #1  */
          PROCEDURE_LINE="1"
          PROCEDURE_CODE="01201"
        
       }
       PROCEDURE { /* #2  */
          PROCEDURE_LINE="2"
          PROCEDURE_CODE="02102"
         
       }
       PROCEDURE { /* #3  */
          PROCEDURE_LINE="3"
          PROCEDURE_CODE="21222"
       
       }
    }
    
    SEND EOB {
          PREFIX="9403        "
          OFFICE_SEQUENCE="000721"
          PROCEDURE { /* #1 */
             PROCEDURE_LINE="1"
             ELIGIBLE="002750"
          }
          PROCEDURE { /* #2 */
             PROCEDURE_LINE="2"
             ELIGIBLE="008725"
          }
          PROCEDURE { /* #3 */
             PROCEDURE_LINE="3"
             ELIGIBLE="010200"
          }
    }
    
    SEND COB {
       PREFIX="TEST4       "
       OFFICE_SEQUENCE="000721"
       PROCEDURE { /* #1  */
          PROCEDURE_LINE="1"
          PROCEDURE_CODE="01201"
        
       }
       PROCEDURE { /* #2  */
          PROCEDURE_LINE="2"
          PROCEDURE_CODE="02102"
       }
       PROCEDURE { /* #3  */
          PROCEDURE_LINE="3"
          PROCEDURE_CODE="21222"
          DATE="19990104"
       }
       PRIME_EOB=SEND EOB {
          PREFIX="9403        "
          OFFICE_SEQUENCE="000721"
          PROCEDURE { /* #1 */
             PROCEDURE_LINE="1"
             ELIGIBLE="002750"
          }
          PROCEDURE { /* #2 */
             PROCEDURE_LINE="2"
             ELIGIBLE="008725"
          }
          PROCEDURE { /* #3 */
             PROCEDURE_LINE="3"
             ELIGIBLE="010200"
          }
    
       }
    }`
    
    let re = /(^\s+PROCEDURE\s\{)([\S\s]*?)(?:})/gm
    
    console.log(data.match(re));
```

Here is what I have tried so far `(^\s+PROCEDURE\s\{)([\S\s]*?)(?:})`, but I can't figure out how I can match `PROCEDURE`s after key `CLAIM` or `EOB`

Comment: Is the section `PRIME_EOB=SEND EOB` to be skipped?

Comment: @CarySwoveland, it should not be skipped, should be included in the results object, my current strategy is to make this a two-step process, first match `CLAIM` section then parse `PROCEDURE` and add it to results object, and so on for other keys. 
if you have a cleaner / better idea that would be great, thanks

Comment: The reason for my confusion is that `"SEND EOB"` appears twice, at two different "levels".

Comment: You'll see that my answer disregards the `PRIME_EOB=SEND EOB`, as I am not clear as to how it should be dealt with.

Answer (score 1):

For "claim", you could match the following regular expression.

```
/(?<=^ *SEND CLAIM +\{\r?\n(?:^(?! *SEND EOB *\{)(?! *SEND COB *\{).*\r?\n)*^ *PROCEDURE *)\{[^\}]*\}/
```

[CLAIM regex](https://regex101.com/r/XroaCh/6/)

This matches the following strings, which I assume can be easily saved to an array with a sprinkling of Javascript code.

```
         { /* CLAIM #1  */  
   PROCEDURE_LINE="1"
   PROCEDURE_CODE="01201"
    
}
```

```
          { /* CLAIM #2  */
   PROCEDURE_LINE="2"
   PROCEDURE_CODE="02102"
  
}
```

```
          { /* CLAIM #3  */
   PROCEDURE_LINE="3"
   PROCEDURE_CODE="21222"
   
}
```

Javascript's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?<=                 : begin positive lookbehind
  ^                  : match beginning of line
  \ *SEND CLAIM\ +   : match 'SEND CLAIM' surrounded by 0+ spaces
  \{\r?\n            : match '{' then line terminators
  (?:                : begin non-capture group
    ^                : match beginning of line
    (?!              : begin negative lookahead
      \ *SEND EOB\ * : match 'SEND EOB' surrounded by 0+ spaces
      \{             : match '{'
    )                : end negative lookahead
    (?!              : begin negative lookahead
      \ *SEND COB\ * : match 'SEND COB' surrounded by 0+ spaces
      \{             : match '{'
    )                : end negative lookahead
    .*\r?\n          : match line including terminators
  )                  : end non-capture group
  *                  : execute non-capture group 0+ times
  ^                  : match beginning of line
  \ *PROCEDURE\ *    : match 'PROCEDURE' surrounded by 0+ spaces 
)                    : end positive lookbehind
\{[^\}]*\}           : match '{', 0+ characters other than '}', '}'
```

I've escaped space characters above to improve readability.

For "eob", use the slightly-modified regex:

```
/(?<=^ *SEND EOB +\{\r?\n(?:^(?! *SEND CLAIM *\{)(?! *SEND COB *\{).*\r?\n)*^ *PROCEDURE *)\{[^\}]*\}/
```

[EOB regex](https://regex101.com/r/XroaCh/7/)

I've made no attempt to do the same for "cob" as that part has a different structure than "claim" and "eob" and it is not clear to me how it is to be treated.

A final note, should it not be obvious: it would be far easier to extract the strings of interest using convention code with loops and, possibly, simple regular expressions, but I hope some readers may find my answer instructive about some elements of regular expressions.

Comment: I think Javascript does not support `\G`

Comment: @Thefourthbird, I too thought JavaScript didn’t support \G but I tried it at regex101 with JavaScript’s engine and it worked! I just double-checked and, oh no, PCRE! What a waste of time! I've revised my answer to take advantage of JS’s support for variable-length lookbehinds. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

Will `CLAIM`, `EOB` and `COB` always be in the same order? If so, you can split the text before using the regex you already have:

```
const procRegex = /(^\s+PROCEDURE\s\{)([\S\s]*?)(?:})/gm;

let claimData = data.split("EOB")[0];
let claimProcedures = claimData.match(procRegex);

let eobData = data.split("COB")[0].split("EOB")[1];
let eobProcedures = eobData.match(procRegex);

let cobData = data.split("COB")[1];
let cobProcedures = cobData.match(procRegex);

// If you want to leave out the PRIME_EOB, you can split COB again
cobData = cobData.split("EOB")[0];
cobProcedures = cobData.match(procRegex);

console.log(claimProcedures);
```

Output:

```
[
  '       PROCEDURE { /* #1  */\n' +
    '          PROCEDURE_LINE="1"\n' +
    '          PROCEDURE_CODE="01201"\n' +
    '        \n' +
    '       }',
  '       PROCEDURE { /* #2  */\n' +
    '          PROCEDURE_LINE="2"\n' +
    '          PROCEDURE_CODE="02102"\n' +
    '         \n' +
    '       }',
  '       PROCEDURE { /* #3  */\n' +
    '          PROCEDURE_LINE="3"\n' +
    '          PROCEDURE_CODE="21222"\n' +
    '       \n' +
    '       }'
]
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/OutrageousRubberyServerapplication#index.js)

As an alternate method, your data is not terribly far away from valid JSON, so you could run with that. The code below translates the data into JSON, then parses it into a Javascript object that you can use however you want.

```
/* data cannot have Javascript comments in it for this to work, or you need
   another regex to remove them */

data = data.replace(/=/g, ":") // replace = with :
  .replace(/\s?{/g, ": {") // replace { with : {
  .replace(/SEND/g, "") // remove "SEND"
  .replace(/\"\s*$(?!\s*\})/gm, "\",") // add commas after object properties
  .replace(/}(?=\s*\w)/g, "},") // add commas after objects
  .replace(/(?<!\}),\s*PROCEDURE: /g, ",\nPROCEDURES: [") // start procedures list
  .replace(/(PROCEDURE:[\S\s]*?\})\s*(?!,\s*PROCEDURE)/g, "$1]\n") // end list
  .replace(/PROCEDURE: /g, "") // remove "PROCEDURE"
  .replace("PRIME_EOB: EOB:", "PRIME_EOB:") // replace double key with single key. Is this the behavior you want?
  .replace(/(\S*):/g, "\"$1\":") // put quotes around object key names

let dataObj = JSON.parse("{" + data + "}");

console.log(dataObj.CLAIM.PROCEDURES);
```

Output:

```
[ { PROCEDURE_LINE: '1', PROCEDURE_CODE: '01201' },
  { PROCEDURE_LINE: '2', PROCEDURE_CODE: '02102' },
  { PROCEDURE_LINE: '3', PROCEDURE_CODE: '21222' } ]
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/OurPortlyLink#script.js)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to write a parser for the syntax used in your text file.
If one looks at the syntax it looks much like JSON.
I would recommend to modify the syntax with regexps to get a valid JSON syntax and parse it with the JavaScript JSON parser. The parser is able to handle recursion. At the end you will have a JavaScript object that allows you to remove- or add whatever you need. In addition the hierarchy of the source will be preserved.

This code does the job for the provided example:

```
let data = `    SEND CLAIM {
// your text file contents
}`;

// handle PRIME_EOB=SEND EOB {
var regex = /(\w+)=\w+.*{/gm;
var replace = data.replace(regex, "$1 {");

// append double quotes in lines like PROCEDURE_LINE="1"
var regex = /(\w+)=/g;
var replace = replace.replace(regex, "\"$1\": ");

// append double quotes in lines like PROCEDURE {
var regex = /(\w+.*)\s{/g;
var replace = replace.replace(regex, "\"$1\": {");

// remove comments: /* */
var regex = /\/\**.*\*\//g;
var replace = replace.replace(regex, "");

// append commas to lines i.e. "PROCEDURE_LINE": "2"
var regex = /(\".*\":\s*\".*\")/gm;
var replace = replace.replace(regex, "$1,");

// append commas to '}'
var regex = /^.*}.*$/gm;
var replace = replace.replace(regex, "},");

// remove trailing commas
var regex = /\,(?!\s*?[\{\[\"\'\w])/g;
var replace = replace.replace(regex, "");

// surround with {}
replace = "{" + replace + "}";

console.log(replace);
var obj = JSON.parse(replace);
console.log(obj);
```

The JSON looks like this snippet:

```
{    "SEND CLAIM": {
       "PREFIX": "9403        ",
       "PROCEDURE": { 
          "PROCEDURE_LINE": "1",
          "PROCEDURE_CODE": "01201"
        
},
       "PROCEDURE": { 
          "PROCEDURE_LINE": "2",
          "PROCEDURE_CODE": "02102"
```

And the final object appears in the debugger like this
[image].

It is not completely clear to me what your final array or object should look like. But from here I expect only little effort to produce what you desire.